# Java Affine Transform Scale()

Tags: java, swing, scale, affinetransform

I'm working on a project in which I'm using Affine Transform to move round object around a JPanel but I'm not seeing the affect I would aspect.

I'm creating the shape using the Area class with constructive geometry. I set it's location and size as part of the constructor with

```
// Set location and size
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(x, y);
at.scale(size, size);

shape.transform(at);
```

This appears to work correctly. The issue I see is when I make a separate call to re-size the shape.

```
/**
 * Scales this shape uniformly by the 
 *   amount of scale about the origin
 * @param scale - double
 */
public void scaleBy(double scale)
{
   double cx = this.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
   double cy = this.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
   double size = this.getBounds2D().getWidth();

   System.out.println("Before ~ Size: " + size + " | Scale: " + scale);

   AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();


   at.translate(cx, cy);
   at.scale(scale, scale);      
   at.translate(-cx, -cy);
   shape.transform(at);

   System.out.println("After ~ Size: " + size + " | Scale: " + scale);
}
```

The prints statements show that there is no change in size before and after the call:

```
Before ~ Size: 159.61132183122953 | Scale: 0.9703729137903474
After ~ Size: 159.61132183122953 | Scale: 0.9703729137903474
Before ~ Size: 84.00595885854187 | Scale: 1.0692249107993637
After ~ Size: 84.00595885854187 | Scale: 1.0692249107993637
```

I guess my question is does the transform not take place until repaint() call is made? If so what would be a good way to restrict the sized to keep the shape between say 30.0 and 150.0 in size

Comment: The transformation won't effect your variables

Comment: While the 'cx' & 'cy' I would not expect to change, shouldn't the 'size' reflect a change in the shapes internal resizing?

Comment: `transform` isn't likely to change the original shape, but instead return a transformed shape...but I don't know what `shape` is so it's difficult to say....

Comment: Shape is an Area constructive geometry representing a Ying Yang symbol. What I'm curious about is the fact that I can call getBounds() on the shape from outside the class (from draw panel) and get back an accurate before and after sampling. Shouldn't the call to `double size = this.getBounds2D().getWidth();` update as the  shape is transformed? One would think that if you can call from outside the class before and after you could get this from inside the class as you are making changes.

Comment: `getBounds` may be returning a cloned copy of the bounds, thus preventing any changes you might make to the `Rectangle` being reflected within in the `Shape` itself.  Also `double size` is not going to be changed as it is simply a snapshot of the value the time it was taken, it won't change unless you reassign a value to it...

Comment: They makes sense though one would think the internals would be updated regardless of where it is created. I'll deal with it as is. Thanks for the input.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I assumed my question was fairly self explanatory. It was a question about how java updates its internals verses getting the information from outside of a class. I just assumed it would be more constructive to make adjustments to a call to re-size in case you wanted to restrict the amount of scale based on its out come. I guess you could manually make the calculations before applying the scale first but that seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the size and scale from local variables obtained *before* applying the transform. Try getting the actual values from the shape instead.

Comment: I do that from the class that I make the calls from (which shows the correct values) but shouldn't the local variables reflect current placement and size characteristics after the call to transform? Am I missing a key concept?

Comment: Apparently so - this line "double size = this.getBounds2D().getWidth()" obtains the value, and its constant in the methods scope after that (you never update it). But you print it twice, as before and after value in the two println statements. Local variables never change state unless you explicitly assign them a different value.

Comment: I dug a little further into the call and it returns a cached copy. You are correct that it will not changed until it is called again.